# How can I create an infix %between% operator?

Tags: r

I would like to have an infix operator `%between%` in `R` -- to check to see if `x` is between lower bound `l` and upper bound `u`.

I have created the following simple function -- but it's not an infix operation.

```
# between function - check to see if x is between l and u
is.between <- function(x, l, u) { x > l & x < u }
```

My aim is to replace this with: `x %between% c(l, u)`

Is it possible to define new infix operations? If so, how does one do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can define infix operators as functions:

```
`%between%`<-function(x,rng) x>rng[1] & x<rng[2]
1 %between% c(0,3)
# [1] TRUE
1 %between% c(2,3)
# [1] FALSE
```

As pointed out by @flodel, this operator is vectorized:

```
1:5 %between% c(1.5,3.5)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: +1 - you should also take credit for providing a vectorized function, by showing an example where `x` has length > 1.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to drop some input validation code in there (but that's an enhancement-- not needed for this answer).  And then, there's the usual options: do you want to be able to include the goalposts (`x<=rng[2]`), and do you want "almost equal" to be allowed or not?   Just pointing out that you have to be careful what you expect out of a simple operator.

Answer (score 12):

This function exists in the package `data.table` (with the slight difference that the bounds are included), implemented as:

```
between <- function(x,lower,upper,incbounds=TRUE)
{
  if(incbounds) x>=lower & x<=upper
  else x>lower & x<upper
}

"%between%" <- function(x,y) between(x,y[1],y[2],incbounds=TRUE)
```

It can be used as `between(x,lower,upper)` or `x %between% c(lower, upper)`

Answer (score 4):

To avoid ambiguity, one could define two functions:

```
"%><%"  <- function(x, rng) x > rng[1]  & x < rng[2]
"%>=<%" <- function(x, rng) x >= rng[1] & x <= rng[2]
x=1:5
x %><% c(2,4)
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
x %>=<% c(2,4)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or even add these two others:

```
"%> =<%"<-function(x,rng) x > rng[1]  & x <= rng[2]
"%>= <%"<-function(x,rng) x >= rng[1] & x < rng[2]
```