# Creating an infix function in R

Tags: r, function, infix-notation, infix-operator

I am reading Advanced R by Hadley. One of the exercises asks us to create our own infix function. I read [creating an infix %between% operator in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441092/creating-an-infix-between-operator-in-r) but I wasn't sure how to create an infix function as:

> %`%

I was able to create infix function in R using other operators (i.e. space between `%` and `%` with grave or grave accent as :

> ```
> `% %` <- function(a,b) paste(a,b)
> "Hello" % % "World"
> rm(`% %`)
> ```

I guess I don't know how to apply the escape sequence for the infix function that I am trying to create with ` (i.e. grave or grave accent)

Comment: You can't do that. `\`` got a special syntactical meaning and can't be used for this. The parser can't deal with it.

Comment: @Roland - Thanks for your help. Am I correct in understanding that ``` can't be used even with an escape sequence?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to escape `\`` for the parser other than wrapping it in quotes (because there is no legitimate use case).

Comment: E.g., how would the parser distinguish a legitimate use such as `\`%\`` from `%\`%`? That edge case would be not so easy to implement and you gain nothing for the language.