# R calling infix function with more than 2 parameters

Tags: r, infix-notation

I liked so much index search of `xts` that I created one for `data.frame`.

```
"%d%"=function(df1,dt,col='dt_pregao') {
  if(regexpr('/',dt)>0){
    dt=strsplit(dt,'/')[[1]]
    return(df1[df1[,col] %>=<% c(dt[1],dt[2]),])}
  return(df1[df1[,col]==dt,])}
```

This works:

```
opx%d%'2018-03-09'
```

I saw that I can put the column name as a parameter.
But how can I pass the third parameter using infix notation? Neither of these works:

```
opx%d%c('2018-03-09','dt_pregao')
(opx%d%'2018-03-09')'dt_pregao'
```

P.S.

```
"%>=<%"<-function(x,rng) x>=rng[1] & x<=rng[2]
```

`opx` example:

```
structure(list(dt_pregao = structure(c(17487, 17487, 17487, 17487, 
17599, 17599, 17599, 17599, 17599, 17599), class = "Date"), cd_papel = c("PETRK16", 
"PETRK81", "PETRK18", "PETRK4", "PETRK47", "PETRK48", "PETRK53", 
"PETRK7", "PETRK70", "PETRK1"), veFech = c(0.08, 0, 0.01, 0.01, 
0.01, 0.01, 0.03, -9.06, 0.12, -0.01)), .Names = c("dt_pregao", 
"cd_papel", "veFech"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It isn't clear what a 3-parameter infix operator would even mean. You could make the second argument be a vector or a list, but would of course have to write the function so that it works with a vector or list. In any event, if you want more specific help, include a [mcve].

Comment: By the way your nice (+1) answer to this question shows that you already know the basic idea of what you need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45714182/4996248

Comment: In this case, it informs the column to search. I will do an example.

Comment: What you could do is pass a character vector as the second argument. If the vector is of length 1, the body of the function could use `"dt_pregao"`, if the vector is of length 2, treat the second element as the name of the column.

Comment: I did it! :) But I think this solution is cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call an infix function with more than 2 arguments you will need to use its prefix form:

```
`%sum%` <- function(x, y, z = 0) x + y + z

4 %sum% 5
## [1] 9

`%sum%`(4, 5, 6)
## [1] 15
```

Alternately redefine it so that it only requires 2 arguments.

Comment: In that special case, there's also `\`%g%\` <- sum; 4 %g% 5; \`%g%\`(4, 5, 6, 7)`